# Is $x\ln(x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f(x) = x\ln(x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$?

I know it is not uniformly continuous over $(0, \infty]$ It seems that it would be over the given interval though.

It is not Lipschitz on this interval as the derivative is not bounded being $f'(x) = \ln(x) + 1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$f$ may be extended by continuity to $[0,1]$ with $f(0) = 0$. It's continuous on $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is compact. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Comment: (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)