# Does continuous imply defined? Specific to f(x)=x.lnx

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I ask this question with reference to [Is $x\ln(x)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398433/is-x-lnx-uniformly-continuous-on-0-1/2398440) where one of the replies say that f(x)= xlnx, f(x)=0, however I know that f(x)=0 cannot be defined since ln0 is defined and therefore 0ln0 is not defined too. But it seems that xlnx is continuous at 0 , which makes me have the question if something is continuous then it must be defined too, otherwise f(x)=0 would not hold in the reply in the above.

The reply of my link says: xlnx  may be extended by continuity to [0,1] with f(0)=0. It's continuous on [0,1] and [0,1] is compact. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

I have included the response , so people do not have to click the link as in the past people have downvoted me for forcing them to click a link..

Pardon my English as my first language is Dutch, thanksa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

$f(x) = x\,\textrm{ln} x$ is not defined at $x=0$ but can easily be extended to a function defined at $x=0$. Just like how $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$ but $\textrm{sinc}(x)$ is the extension of that function at $x=0$.

So we can define
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases}
x\,\textrm{ln} x\ &\textrm{if}&\ x&>&0 \\
0 \ &\textrm{if}&\ x&=&0
\end{cases}$$
and we find that $g(x)$ is continuous and well defined at $0$.

Comment: but in reference to the answer I posted, the person said that f(x)=xlnx without defining anything new,so why is that so?

Comment: They said it can be extended to $[0,1]$. This is true. Really they meant to a new function, say $g$, like I defined. This is often not stated though as it is usually obvious what is meant.

Comment: but if you extend the function, isn't this a new function of x.lnx and not the same one anymore?

Comment: so whatever deductions we make on the new function would not necesarily hold onto the old one?

Comment: The new function is the same as the old one except at $x=0$. So any deductions on the new one apply on the old one except at $x=0$. It basically is the same function, its just you cannot properly talk about the value of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ but rather the limit as $x\to 0$. To avoid this, one just defines the value as the limit, this is what is meant by extending the function.

Comment: technically the "old" function is a restriction of the "new" function so properties that are preserved under restriction still work - uniform continuity is such a property (being onto a specific domain, for example, is not generally preserved under restriction)

Comment: if I did not define f(x)=0, would the function still be considered continuous?

Comment: or only if I define f(x)=0 then I can start talking about continuity?

Comment: @JosephRock : Neither the question at your link nor your quotation of it include "$x \ln x$", so to say "the person said that f(x)=xlnx without defining anything new" is false.  Cauchy said no such thing.  Cauchy said $f$ can be extended [to a new function] by continuity to [the slightly larger domain] $[0,1]$.  This literally means that Cauchy constructs a new function with a new domain.  Now the old $f$ and the extension of $f$ agree at every point of $(0,1]$.  Any uniformity claim for the extended function holds at every point of the restriction to $(0,1]$, the given $f$.